# Getting an output based on conditions and creating a new column and updating it based on a condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

We have two tables: “riders” and “drivers”. Some riders are also drivers, so will show up on both tables. Each
table looks like this:

Table riders

[image: Table riders]

```
City | user_id | signup_date
SF   | u1      | 3/12
CH   | u2      | 12/12
SF   | u3      | 5/10
```

I have tried this code:

```sql
SELECT riders.id, 'flag' as flag FROM riders INNER JOIN drivers ON riders.id = drivers.id where riders.City ='SF';
```

Write a query that outputs all SF riders and add a column called ‘flag’ that prints ‘true’ if the rider is also a SF driver and ‘false’ if the rider is not an SF driver.

My output should look like a column of user_id and flag

```
user_id | flag
u1      | true    if u1 is also in Table 'drivers'
u3      | false   if u3 is not in Table 'drivers' but in City SF
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a full [mre]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results *as text in the question* would really help!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated.

Comment: users2 u2 and u4 will not be in output, INNER JOIN, by mistake I wrote LEFT JOIN. But still I have problem in updating 'flag' column with true or false. Also, flag column I have to add to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but your query has two problems:

- The definition of `flag` is just a constant.
- Your `join` conditions are not correct.

You need to `JOIN` the tables on the `user_id` and then check if there is a match in the second table:

```
SELECT r.user_id, (d.user_id is not null) as flag
FROM riders r LEFT JOIN
     drivers d
     ON r.user_id = d.user_id
WHERE riders.City = 'SF';
```

If you want `true` and `false` as strings:

```
(CASE WHEN d.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)
```

Comment: yes it is working, only thing is 1 and 0 is written in place of true and false. How can i put true and false inplace of 1 and 0?